# Does angular/react/vue application have the concept of session timeout?

Tags: angular, session, webforms, session-state

When we were upgrading our current server-side application (ASP.NET WebForM) to these client-side SPA like using Angular/React/Vue, do any of these application still have the concept of session time out? In my opinion, these client application could live as long as they want, because all data request are being post/get using the REST API, there is no session needed to keep these application alive or maintain part of the data stored (there is state management like Ngrx or Redux but I think those might be different concepts regarding the server-session), if so, do we still need session timeout feature in these application? What'd be the benefit or drawback of session timeout design there?

Comment: This question would be better suited for the [software engineering stack exchange](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score -1):

This might not you looking for, In PHP i used session management to logout application. Here In SPA application, we use JWT our any other method for token generation, we can logout the user by invalidating the access token for particular time period.

Or for a work-around we can save token in client browser cookie and give a cookie expire time.